# Recognize Arabic Text In Egyptian Id With ML-Kit In Android | Arabic Text Recognize

Tags: android, ocr, google-mlkit

I was trying to do text recognition using ML-Kit but, Arabic is not supported in [the list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android#1_create_an_instance_of_textrecognizer).

So, I was wondering how can I do that using ML-Kit or any other service.

Example Image

[image]

I'm interested in getting data for numbers from 1-8 values, in specific tags so I can re-use it to pass correct data to API.

can someone suggest to me how to achieve that, please?

I'm open to using any service/API to get these data.

Note: I've tried out **[tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#cube-data-files-for-version-304305)** but it gives me text as one bulk from 1-8 so I couldn't parse them into values for APIs

Comment: If MLKit officially document that it doesn't support Arabic, then you have to switch to other APIs. For example, using the google cloud API: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

Comment: @jack can you please guide me with a sample after reading the docs couldn't know how to merge these Google Cloud APIs into MLKit.